# How to produce a deterministic monochrome pseudo-random organic pattern?

Tags: random, graphics

Given an X-Y grid, I'd like to deterministically calculate whether each point was black of white.

The overall effect should be a pseudo-random organic pattern, where a randomly placed line, of length `L`, should cross approximately `L/10` black/white boundaries.

An example of such a pattern is:

[image: example]

which has both areas of white with block blobs and areas of black with white blobs.

Comment: do you have any image of wanted result?  your description is too vague to me ... do you want something like [Game of Life](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conway%27s_Game_of_Life) ?

Comment: @Spektre Thanks for your comment, I've added an example.

Comment: looks similar to [perlin noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise) to me ... maybe + some binarization / erosion / dilatation

Comment: or its just grayscale perlin noise dithered by B&W blobs